# Проблема с настройкой нумерации строк в Vim

Tags: vim

При настройки нумерации строк с параметром "set number" в Vim фон нумерации строк съезжает на право над основным экраном, как можно исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Такое происходит после добавления параметра нумерции строки...

set number

можно как то исправить это ?

Comment: Это скорее всего эффект от `set cursorcolumn` т.е. подсвечивается текущий (0-ой) столбец.

Comment: Спасибо большое!